# Docker time measures in unified unit

Tags: docker

I have a problem with parsing output of `docker ps` command. To be more precise, with time containing fields.

The command returns time in format like this:
`53 minutes`,
`About an hour`,
`5 hours`
and I am unable to compare those values programmatically.

Is there any way to choose output format or at least unit?

Thanks for your help.

PS. I am just asking, whether I need to write a script/regexp to parse it or there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can have the exact value with `docker inspect`

try

`docker inspect -f '{{ .Created }}' container_id`

see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/